# Express session store and reapInterval

Tags: session, node.js, express

I have a question about express session store memory with setting the reapInterval value. I have an example code, which will output the values of a memorystore every 5 seconds. If i now set a reapinterval of 5000, it should clean up expired session every 5 seconds right? So my example looks like this:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
var MemStore = require('express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory');
var store = new MemStore({reapInterval: 5000});

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({secret: 'your secret here', store: store, cookie: {maxAge: 30000}}));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

setInterval(function(){
    console.log(new Date());
    console.log(store);
}, 5000);

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});

// Routes

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
     title: 'Express'
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

And now the problem is, that if I revisit the page after 30 seconds, I get a new SID, but the old session in memorystore is still there... should it not be checked every 5 seconds and deleted?

Thx for your help!

Comment: Why even bother with this? In production you'll either use something like connect-redis or connect-mongo for session storage? :)

Comment: Any luck resolving this? I ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

So the first problem is a misunderstanding here. reapInterval does not do anything. MemoryStore clears cookies based on the expire time of session cookie. So there is in fact a bug in Connects MemoryStore. The way I see it the broken flow goes like this.

- Set cookie to expire in X.
- Get session data, has X gone by? No, ok.
- (cookie expires)
- Get session data, session doesn't exist, generate new one.
- X has gone by but the session ID is missing because the browser expired it already.

There is a discussion regarding this here.

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/328

And a juicy quote

"short cookie sessions would be screwed I guess" --visionmedia

Comment: You can also look at ```MemoryStore.prototype.get``` to see how this works.